# How to make wordpress post design in two column layout post type

Tags: php, wordpress

My website is [Career Tracker](http://careertracker.net/)

I want to design wordpress like column-wise 2 columns

Like this

```
post1     post2

post3     post4

post5     post6
```

Any idea how to make this ...in wordpress ??

I know easy way

```
 query_posts('category_name=Bank Jobs&amp;showposts=10');

 while (have_posts()) : the_post();
 {

 }
```

but I want to display result in two columns.

Comment: i am a developer and desingner tooo.... i want to know how to write Query ?

Comment: query_posts('category_name=Bank Jobs&amp;showposts=10');
 while (have_posts()) : the_post();
{
}

I know this way but i want to desing it in two collumn

Comment: so is it too hard to write a container with a certain width and then position two divs into it with `float:left;` ??

Comment: we can write this with for loop but i dont know how...

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: check my answer savan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $count = 0;     
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> // this is your loop
        if($count == 2){ // here is the condition that when the count comes to 2 it will break  th e line
  echo '</div><div class="right">'; $count = 0;
 }
    echo $post->post_content(); // printing the content of post

$count++;
     <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: You should use $count % 2 == 0 to work with more than 2 posts

Comment: Thanx @SvenSchneider but i want to add 1 div like right div and left div ...how can i do ?

Comment: No need here because whenever `count` comes to `2`, I have set `$count = 0;` again. :)

Comment: thank you
@MoeedFarooqui :)

so can i place make desing like this into this loop
<div id="post">
echo $post->post_content(); 
</div>

Comment: Yes it is a normal div as you are a designer you must know how to do styling in it... :) here `$post->post_content();` is just print the post's content.